# Which Audio file would stream faster?

Tags: html

This has been really confusing for me as i want my website to load as fast as i could possible make it load.

I have audios on my website but i am streaming them off from dropbox.
I am not sure whether streaming them from dropbox is a good idea or streaming the audios from within my root directory is better because i also don't want my website to be large in size.

So my question is which is better? Streaming from dropbox or streaming directly from the audio folder within my website.

Comment: Do you have unlimited (or enough to stream each request) bandwidth on your server?

Comment: I have unlimited bandwidth

Comment: One thing to consider is that while your website may be up all the time, dropbox (or any other external provider) may have an outage which means your website won't be working as expected. This is why even though we use CDN's for things like jQuery, we still have a local fallback that is used just in case.

Comment: Okay that makes sense as i didn't think about when or if dropbox is down it will affect my website. So i think streaming locally from my root folder would be better.. just one thing will that affect the load time on my website as the audio are 109MB in size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on many things.

1. **Do you have unlimited (or enough to stream each request
   bandwidth on your server?** If your server has limited bandwidth, go with dropbox.
2. **What is your target audience? Local or
   global?** 
   If local, stream directly from your server (will be faster
   but depends on your server's upload speed) because if dropbox has no
   server close to your area, it will be a bit slower.
3. **Do you have enough file space for both options?** If you want to upload your audio files regularly, after a while you will need to have a bigger space.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes i have unlimited bandwidth and my target audience is both local and global its actually a nature sound website where you can hear sounds of nature. That is why i am wondering which would be better as i don't want my visitors to wait forever for my site to load and i have enough space to upload,i have around 30GB of space so its more than enough

Comment: Keep in mind: Some services like Dropbox may be banned in some countries like us (Turkey, because we love democracy.), so your visitors may have problems reaching your content. Use both servers one for fallback as Jamie said above comments. If i were you, i would use my own server in this case.

Comment: I had no idea of dropbox being banned in some countries thanks for letting me know. I will just stream directly from my server as the audio files sum up to 109MB in size. The only question, Will that affect the loading time of my site?

Comment: Short answer is no. Long answer is: Do you want to play all your audio files at the same time on document ready? If not, again, no; If you want to allow users can play pressing some buttons that will not be a problem because the audio file they wanted will start streaming (loading) after making the request. But, but; If your server's upload speed is slow and your web server configuration is not good enough, you may have a problem.

Comment: No the audio files will only play when the user presses the play button,it does not automatically play all of them and my server upload speed is also pretty good.Thank you for your answer you cleared up stuff for me :)